# Show cell data within listFilesInFolder Function

Tags: java, javascript

I have this formula, which successfully lists all of my files in a folder.  Awesome.  But, can I also, within this script list some specific cell data from each file?

```
function listFilesInFolder() {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder("1- Summaries");
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var file;
  var data;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear();

  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Type"]);

  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    file = contents[i];

    if (file.getFileType() == "SPREADSHEET") {
      continue;
    }

    data = [ 
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getValue(B10),  **(THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO GET DATA, but it does not work)**
      file.getUrl(),
      "https://docs.google.com/a/acme.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=" + file.getId(),
      file.getDescription(),
      "audio/mp3"
    ]

    sheet.appendRow(data);
```

Comment: Why do you have "audio/mp3" as a constant? Did you mean to use file.getFileType()?

Comment: Phil- yes, thanks...

But do you know of anyway to, within this script, also return actual data from within the files (a cell or range)?

Answer (score 0):

You can read from the spreadsheet, yes.

In the place where `if (file.getFileType()...` is, put this:

```
var cellValue;
if (file.getFileType() === "SPREADSHEET") {
  cellValue = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheetByName("NameOfSheet")
      .getRange("B10").getValue();
} else {
  cellValue = null; // specify some default value here!
}
  ...
```

Then in your data array:

```
data = [ 
  file.getName(),
  file.getDateCreated(),
  cellValue,
...
```

Comment: Phil, I hate to ask, but I am kinda new to this and am having problems incorporating your advice into my original script above... Could you show me where you would add this?

Comment: Thank you again, Phil, the code runs and I get the file name, the date created, but the cellValue just returns nothing.  I have checked to make sure the spreadsheet in the folder does have a value in B10

Comment: Did you change the name of the sheet to "Sheet1" or whatever it is?

Comment: This is what I have now: Any thoughts?
  ...
  sheet.appendRow(["link to sheet", "Name", "Type", "Primary Contact"]);
  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    file = contents[i];
    
    var cellValue; if (file.getFileType() === "SPREADSHEET") { cellValue = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheetByName("Sheet1") .getRange('B7,c7,h9').getValue(); } else { cellValue = null; // No Data }
        
    data = [ file.getUrl(),cellValue ]
      
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }
  }};

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `getRange('B7,c7,h9')` part? If you're trying to select non-adjacent cells, that won't work. Try [this code that allows you to combine multiple cells](http://pastebin.com/YsTQnJkc).

Comment: Still not working... I could not seem to edit my question with my complete updated code, so I created another question with my current updated code...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800195/cant-seem-to-read-cell-data-from-another-google-spreadsheet-in-my-script