# Cant seem to read cell data from another google spreadsheet in my script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my script.  It returns the url for each sheet in the folder "My folder", but returns no cell value that I am asking for. Can anyone see what is wrong?  I have checked the spreadsheets to make sure there are values in the cells referenced.
     `function onOpen() {
      var folder = DocsList.getFolder("My folder");
      var contents = folder.getFiles();

```
  var file;
  var data;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clearContents(); 
  sheet.appendRow(["link to sheet", "Name", "Type", "Primary Contact"]); 
for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) { 
  file = contents[i];
  var cellValue; 
  if (file.getFileType() === "SPREADSHEET") { 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheetByName("Site Demographics");
    var value1 = sheet.getRange('B7').getValue();
    var value2 = sheet.getRange('C7').getValue();
    var value3 = sheet.getRange('H9').getValue();
    cellValue = ""+value1 + value2 + value3;
  } else {
    cellValue = null; // No Data
  }
  data = [ file.getUrl(),cellValue ]
  sheet.appendRow(data);
}
};`
```

Comment: Because I didn't know what you were doing, I have you some code that doesn't do what you want. [Try this instead](http://pastebin.com/nSSX2qam).

Comment: still the same result... it returns the url but where the data from the cells should be there, it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should check if a file is of a given type by doing this

```
if (file.getFileType()==DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET)
```

Also, you are reusing the variable `sheet`. Consider renaming the second usage of it to `otherSheet`.

Comment: If I use if (file.getFileType() === "SPREADSHEET"), I get the url but nothing else.  If I use if (file.getFileType()==DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET) it does not even return the url.

Comment: Are there any errors that it's showing you?
From the script editor, click the run button. See if it tells you any errors.

Comment: Phil, I created an example which is editable.  There is a "TESTING FOLDER".  It contains one "master sheet" which has the script in it.  There is also a "My folder" with two spreadsheets for the code to reference.  Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Problem solved. You were using the variable `sheet` to mean 2 different things. Renaming one of them solved the issue.

Comment: We Are soooo close and thank you for your help.  Now, it IS returning cell values... but it is just returning one row for one of the spreadsheets in "my folder" and not both of them.  In practice, there will be many spreadsheets in that folder that I want to list on the "master sheet" with data.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough.  Would I could, I would send you a virtual beer!